# Cofibrant approximation of maps. [Hirschhorn 8.1.23]

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

In [Hirschhorn 8.1.23] (page 142) the author claims the following:

> Let $g: X \to Y$ be a any map in a general model category
> $\mathcal{M}$ (with functorial factorization), then there exists
> *cofibrant* objects $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}$  together with trivial fibrations $\tilde{Y}\xrightarrow{i_Y} Y$ and
> $\tilde{X}\xrightarrow{i_X} X$ and a map $\tilde{g}:\tilde{X}\to
>  \tilde{Y}$ that is a *cofibration* and is such that the obvious square commutes, that is: $i_Y \circ
>  \tilde{g}=g \circ i_X$.

Hirschhorn proof is the following:

> take $i_X:\tilde{X} \to X$ the cofibrant approximation of $X$ induced
> by the functorial factorization which we have by axiom, then compose
> it with $g$. Factorize $g \circ i_X$ as a cofibration $\tilde{g}$
> followed by a trivial fibration $\tilde{X}\xrightarrow{\tilde{g}} E
>  \xrightarrow{i} Y$ and put $\tilde{Y} = E$.

**Question**

> My problem with this proof is that I see no reason why $E$ should be a
> cofibrant object. Probably I am missing something obvious, what am I
> missing?

Comment: For those of us who don't have this text to refer to it would be better to state your hypotheses clearly. Presumably $g : X \to Y$ is a map in a model category of some kind; what kind exactly? What are you assuming about it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $g$ is any map in a model category. The model category has no hypothesis. The definition of model structure is the standard one, with functorial factorizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tilde X$ is cofibrant and $\tilde g$ is a cofibration, the composition $0\to \tilde X\to E$ is a cofibration and $E$ is cofibrant.

Comment: of course! jesus I don't know how I was missing this haha. thanks

Comment: @lola it happens! Always like being able to give a plain and simple answer.